# Hibernate 5 can't compare string with int

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, compare, hibernate-criteria

I migrate hibernate from version `4.3.7` to `5.3.7`
Currently my code goes like this

```
public BcData findByBcCode(int clearingNumber) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<BcData> query = cb.createQuery(BcData.class);
        Root<BcData> bcAlias = query.from(BcData.class);
        query.where(cb.equal(bcAlias.get(BcData_.bcCode), clearingNumber));
        return findSingle(query, new HashMap<>());
    }
```

So in DB, `bcCode` has type `String`, values `00437`, `22437` and clearingNumber = 437.

In hibernate version `4.x`, it can get result with `bcCode = 00437`.

In version `5.x`, result is null unless the input is `clearingNumber = 00437`

So question is that how can I get result same as version `4` without changing param type `(int clearingNumber)`.

Thanks.
Update 1:
Inside method equal, it takes input param as object, so generally it can compare many type of input parameters

```
@Override
    @SuppressWarnings("SuspiciousNameCombination")
    public Predicate equal(Expression<?> x, Object y) {
        return new ComparisonPredicate( this, ComparisonOperator.EQUAL, x, y );
    }
```

Update 2:
finally I found a solution for this, we should parse bcCode as int before querying

```
Expression<Integer> bcCodeExpr = bcAlias.get(BcData_.bcCode).as(Integer.class);
query.where(cb.equal(bcCodeExpr, clearingNumber));
```

Comment: how did the SQL look like that 4.3.7 was generating? There must have been some magic

Comment: Sounds really dodgy

Answer (score 0):

It should have not worked in the beginning. You probably hot lucky with how your string was casted into an integer.

It is not very smart to compare String with int. I would convert the string into an int by hand and then compare them. Or you need to somehow delete all trailing spaces in bcCode and then compare them as string with string.